# Ansible module to create VMware Workstation VMs

Tags: ansible, vmware-workstation

I see in Ansible, there is vsphere_guest module to create and manage VMware vSphere VMs.

Same way, is there a module/option, to create VM on VMware Workstation using Ansible?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no module to create and manage VMs on VMware Workstation in Ansible.

All Ansible modules for VMware products are [listed here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_cloud_modules.html#vmware).

Answer (score 0):

There is a package available on GitHub that looks promising.
https://github.com/qsypoq/Ansible-VMware-Workstation-Fusion-Pro-Modules

The author explains the rationale on a blog post.
https://magnier.io/developing-vmware-workstation-pro-ansible-module